# UnicodeDecodeError with Django's request.FILES

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in the view call..

```
def view(request):
    body = u""  
    for filename, f in request.FILES.items():
        body = body + 'Filename: ' + filename + '\n' + f.read() + '\n'
```

On some cases I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 7470: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong? (I am using Django 1.1.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django has some [utilities](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions) that handle this (smart_unicode, force_unicode, smart_str).  Generally you just need smart_unicode.

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
def view(request):
    body = u""  
    for filename, f in request.FILES.items():
        body = body + 'Filename: ' + filename + '\n' + smart_unicode(f.read()) + '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks and i am going to upvote all of you once registered =)

Comment: For anybody who faces the problem nowadays; smart_unicode got renamed to smart_text https://github.com/release-engineering/kobo/pull/123

Answer (score 4):

you are appending f.read() directly to unicode string, without decoding it, if the data you are reading from file is utf-8 encoded use utf-8, else use whatever encoding it is in.

**decode it first and then append to body** e.g.

```
data = f.read().decode("utf-8")
body = body + 'Filename: ' + filename + '\n' + data + '\n'
```

Answer (score 4):

Anurag's answer is correct. However another problem here is you can't for certain know the encoding of the files that users upload. It may be useful to loop over a tuple of the most common ones till you get the correct one:

```
encodings = ('windows-xxx', 'iso-yyy', 'utf-8',)
for e in encodings:
    try:
        data = f.read().decode(e)
        break
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not in control of the file encoding for files that can be uploaded , you can guess what encoding a file is in using the [Universal Encoding Detector](http://chardet.feedparser.org/) module `chardet`.